# AngularJS + Canvas and background image replacing

Tags: css, angularjs, canvas, background

I'm using module of AngularJs which draws polygons on selected area. 
Demo available below : 
https://sedrakpc.github.io/
as we can see here, image is populated by background:url css property 
[image]

My goal is to replace that image based on drop-down select. I took some research on parts of code from module :

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

                var activePoint, settings = {};
                var $canvas, ctx, image;

                settings.imageUrl = scope.imageUrl;

                if(!scope.points) {
                    scope.points = [[]];
                }

                if(!scope.active) {
                    scope.active = 0;
                }

                $canvas = $('<canvas>');
                ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

                image = new Image();
                scope.resize = function() {
                    $canvas.attr('height', image.height).attr('width', image.width);
                    $canvas.attr('height', $canvas[0].offsetHeight).attr('width', $canvas[0].offsetWidth);
                    scope.draw();
                };
                $(image).load(scope.resize);
                image.src = settings.imageUrl;
                if (image.loaded) scope.resize();
                $canvas.css({background: 'url('+image.src+')'});
                $canvas.css({backgroundSize: 'contain'});
```

I'm expecting that I should be able to replicate part of code and just replace

```
                $canvas.css({background: 'url('+image.src+')'});
```

with my image ( I don't want to change anything else than background ) . I tried to do it on two ways, but it doesn't work:

```
$scope.undo = function(){ 

    $scope.imageSrc = "http://localhost:3333/img/1.jpg"; 

    var $canvas, ctx, image;

    $canvas = $('<canvas>');
    ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

    $canvas.css({background: 'url('+$scope.imageSrc+')'});
    $canvas.css({backgroundSize: 'contain'});
    // second way 
        var background = new Image();
        background.src = $scope.imageSrc;
        background.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   

        }



};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("canvas").css("background-image", 'url("http://localhost:3333/img/'+id+'.png")');
```

Worked ;-)